# GROUP BY based on String value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a locale field like this:

```
Id, locale
1, "en-US"
2, "en-BR"
3, "en-SK"
4, "fr-FR"
5, "fr-FS"
```

I want to do a select on this table, and group based on "en" or "fr" (part of the locale field string), what should i write to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you may also use the LEFT() function

```
SELECT left(locale, 2), count(id) FROM table group by left(locale, 2)
```

At the end of the day, the important part is to make use of a `group by` statement which contains a function.

Note that this works in MySQL very well. Other DBMS might not like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `substring` and `instr`.

```
select substring(locale,1,instr(locale,'-')-1), count(*)
from tablename
group by substring(locale,1,instr(locale,'-')-1)
```

Comment: I think all locale data uses 2 character language codes, so it should be safe to just take the left 2 character. Otherwise, this should work fine.

Comment: You can assign an alias to the `substring()` expression in the `SELECT` clause and use the alias in the `GROUP BY` clause; it makes the query easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by substring function result

```
SELECT SUBSTR(locale,1,2) FROM table GROUP BY SUBSTR(locale,1,2)
```

Comment: It's good to remember that GROUP BY can be filled with functions or other expressions like case, same thing for ORDER BY.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `substring_index()`:

```
Select substring_index(locale, '-', 1) as grp, count(*)
From t
Group by grp
```

This is simple and general, in the sense of taking all characters before the first separator.